# Converting "zero"-"nine" to 0-9 in C++

Tags: c++

This is a self study question from Stroustrups "Programming:Principles and Practice Using C++". I have the second edition. If this has been answered please feel free to provide a link as I have found none that directly associate with the requirements of this question.

> Build a program that takes an input "zero"-"nine" or 0-9 and convert either or to their string or numerical form.

I have successfully converted numerical to word form but do not have the right structure in mind for the like wise. This is at a stage in the book where only the basics like if/for/while statements, operators, and vectors have been introduced. Please do let me know if this question is not on par with the expectations of this forum as I am taking a serious approach at learning this language.

(I have disabled the portions of the code that does not compute at this time)

```
#include "C:\Users\***********\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects/std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
/**int zero;
string one;
string two;
string three;
string four;
string five;
string six;
string seven;
string eight;
string nine;
**/
int input;
vector<string>words = 
 {"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
cout << "Please enter a number between 0 and 9" << '\n';
cin >> input;
if ((input == 0) || (input == 1) || (input == 2) || (input == 3) || (input == 4) || (input == 5) || (input == 6) || (input == 7) || (input == 8) || (input == 9)) {
    cout << words[input] << '\n';
     }
}

/**if ((input == zero) || (input == one) || (input == two) || (input == three) || (input == four) || (input == five) || (input == six) || (input == seven) || (input == eight) || (input == nine)) {}
**/
```

Comment: Have you considered `if(input >= 0 && input < words.size())` or ?

Comment: You could consider using a "HashMap"/"HashTable"/"Dictionary". It's a common data structure that maps something to something else. E.g. `"three"` to `3` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: Just use `std::find` or lookup in a loop to find your string in the vector. It is not the most efficient way, but for 10 elements and especially for learning is good enough.

Comment: One of the basic steps in learning how to program is doing all the necessary steps manually. The other important step is breaking up a problem is subtasks. You seem to struggle with both. Ideally, you'd have the program done, except for the smallest subtask you can't solve. Post that here. The code above isn't - it doesn't even ask for a word (subtask 1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've put the quote from the book into a block format to break up the initial paragraph, and removed "Thanks!" Chatty content like "Thanks", "Hi" and other 'padding' are discouraged, though usually not enough to justify an edit on their own--I simply removed it because I was block-quoting the passage. You might also want to have a look at the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), since you seemed to have some trouble with your code block.

Comment: Pretty simple exercise if variable is string then compare if string == "one" then output int n=1. Ect.

Comment: As to other issues, I'm not sure what went wrong. Sometimes I think we focus on recycling code, using the most optimum solution, or simply following random standards for no real purpose, that something simple algorithm, for loop and some ibranching, is lost on us. What should be taught is the critical functionality of the c standard. Leave all the optimization for a project that requires it or it is put on sensible grounds.

Comment: Like if your learning basic vectors and trying to wrap your head around them for first time, then add pointers too, and someone comes in describing how you shouldn't be even using arrays and instead vector class and then off on some path about interface inheritance etc, etc. Your simply failing to effectively learn the concepts you set out to learn.

Comment: I recommend just reading the languages syntax standards instead of this book, or maybe just use the book for light reading, rather than learning study guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* certain this is a good question for C++ since it's relatively easy to do with just the legacy C parts of the language.

However, I'll make a couple of notes:

- There's nothing to gain in using vectors for fixed size arrays. You can use normal arrays (same as C) or, probably better, `std::array`, since it carries the size information with it.
- You're almost always better off having reusable functions rather than trying to create everything in `main`. I would suggest two separate functions, one for string-to-int and one for the other way.
- Rather than have a large `if` construct, you should use the library facilities to make life easier (yes, even the legacy C ones if they serve the purpose).

To that end, you may want to examine the following example program which will give you what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

namespace {
    // Only visible to this unit, make const to return as ref.

    const std::array<const std::string, 10> words = {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    const std::string empty;
}

// Convert a word to numeric value, -1 if no good.

int toInt(const std::string &num) {
    // Just check all possible words.

    for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i)
        if (num == words[i])
            return i;

    return -1;
}

// Convert a single-digit numeric string to word string, empty if invalid.

const std::string &toStr(const std::string &num) {
    // Must be single numeric character.

    if ((num.size() != 1) || (strchr("0123456789", num[0]) == nullptr))
        return empty;

    return words[num[0] - '0'];
}

// Simple test harness, just check all arguments passed.

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        int asInt = toInt(argv[i]);
        if (asInt >= 0) {
            std::cout << "'" << argv[i] << "' as numeric = " << asInt << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::string asStr = toStr(argv[i]);
            if (! asStr.empty()) {
                std::cout << "'" << argv[i] << "' as alpha = " << asStr << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "*** '" << argv[i] << "' is not valid input" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```